Unable to Generate Logs with Logbook in Spring Boot WebFlux Project
I'm working on a Spring Boot WebFlux project and trying to use Logbook to log HTTP requests and responses. However, I'm not seeing any logs being generated.
Here is the relevant section of my pom.xml:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
    <artifactId>logbook-spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
    <artifactId>logbook-spring-boot-webflux-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
    <artifactId>logbook-netty</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.0</version>
</dependency>

And here is the relevant part of my application.yml configuration:
logbook:
  format: json
  strategy: default
  filter:
    enabled: true
    exclude:
      - /swagger
      - /api-docs
      - /actuator
  obfuscate:
    headers:
      - Authorization
      - Cookie
    parameters:
      - password
    body:
      patterns:
        - '"password": ".*"'
  write:
    level: DEBUG
    category: logbook.log
  max-body-size: 1000
  exclude:
    content-types:
      - application/octet-stream

Despite this setup, I'm not getting any logs from Logbook in the console or log files. Am I missing something in my configuration? Is there a specific setup needed for Logbook to work with WebFlux?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Please, try to add this code
@Configuration
public class LogbookConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public WebFilter logbookServerFilter(final Logbook logbook) {
    return new LogbookWebFilter(logbook);
  }
}

But, Logbook bean autowires without any customisations via application.yaml...
